# Signed Java Applet prompting for printer access

Tags: java, security, printing, permissions, applet

I have a small java applet that does custom printing from the browser.

I have signed the applet with a go daddy certificate, but I am still receiving the following security warning:

==

Security warning

The applet has requested access to the printer

Do you want to allow this action?

==

There is a checkbox that says, "Always allow this applet to run", but selecting that still always causes the warning dialog to show before the print dialog is displayed.

Is there anyway to grant access to the printer without modifying the .policy file on the client machines or to include a .policy file in the .jar file?

Thanks!

Comment: With your current applet, are you prompted to trust the code before it ever appears?  Try this again with an entirely sand-boxed applet.  Does it behave the same way?  I suspect that the JVM is not recognizing that the applet is signed, and further suspect recent versions of Java will allow sand-boxed applets to print after a run-time trust dialog is OK'd by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is other way. I had the same problem - signed applet printing, but with that annoying dialog.

My problem was that the applet was executed by javascript. According a note [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html), applet executed by javascipt behaves always like unsigned one.